# Prove that montonicity and continuity imply bijectivity.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here's the question:

Let $f: [a,b] \to [f(a),f(b)]$ be monotonically increasing and continuous. Prove that $f$ is bijective.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $f: [a,b] \to [f(a),f(b)]$ be monotonically increasing and continuous. Since it is monotonically increasing, it is injective. So, all we have to do is to prove surjectivity.

Let $K \in (f(a),f(b))$. We define the following sets:

$$E = \{x \in [a,b]: f(x) < K\}$$

Since $E$ is nonempty and bounded above, it follows that it has a least upper bound. We denote this by $c = \sup(E)$. Now, I claim that:

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = K$$

This, in fact, follows from the monotonicity of $f$. If we want $|f(x)-K| < \epsilon$, then we can always choose a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $0 < c-x < \delta_1 \implies |f(x)-K| < \epsilon$. Similarly, we can always choose a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $0 < x-c < \delta_2 \implies |f(x)-K| < \epsilon$.

In other words, the left & right hand limits are $K$ so the limit above is $K$. Since $f$ is continuous, we conclude that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = K = f(c)$. However, this just shows that $f$ is surjective. Hence, $f$ is injective and surjective so it must be bijective.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it? The specific thing that I'm a little unsure of is if my second last paragraph is justified or not. Like, I'm pretty sure the argument works for the left-hand limit but I'm pretty ehh about the right-hand limit.

Comment: Are you supposed to do this without invoking the Intermediate Value Theorem? Because that shows surjectivity rather easily.

Comment: @Reveillark In fact, it looks like he is reproving the IVT in a sense.

Comment: Yeap, I'm supposed to do this without that. This was an exercise given in my topology text and since the intermediate value theorem is proved later, I think I want to try and not use it.

Comment: @FiMePr Yeah, this is essentially the topology-free proof of the IVT, with the added assumption that $f$ is increasing.

Comment: I would definitely say you need some further details about finding $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$. Note IVT says that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)<K<f(b)$ then there is $c$ such that $f(c)=K$. So from a "purity" standpoint you should aim to prove that part without monotonicity (and only use monotonicity to ensure injectivity as you have done).

Comment: Oh hmm let me think about that

Comment: Maybe the more relevant point is that you definitely *need* continuity to prove $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=K$. It won't follow just using monotonicity as your proof suggests.

Comment: Let me have a go at it just using continuity, I suppose. The trouble is that I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to proceed, whether I'm supposed to be looking for some kind of contradiction or if the proof should be direct. I'll try a few things out and maybe edit the post with further updates, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : Do you understand intuitively (I suggest a drawing) why you can get arbitrarily close to $K$ on both sides of $c$ ?

Comment: Well, initially, I was thinking of using the monotonicity of $f$ to guarantee that it gets arbitrarily close to $K$ on both sides of $c$. But based on the comment above, I probably need to invoke continuity in some way. I understand why it makes sense intuitively but formalizing it is turning out to be slightly more tricky for me. Could I have another hint with regards to that?

Comment: Hint: Since $f$ is continuous you know $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$. You want to show $f(c)=K$, so fix an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and show $|f(c)-K|<\epsilon$. Now that you have $\epsilon$, you can start leveraging the definition of continuity.

Comment: Alright let me try that since I'm a little more awake now and fresh to attack the problem. Thanks for the hint haha